# Why wont My Variable Appear In The TextBox Using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am having a little trouble here. im building a calculator and im working on the general idea on it and im confused on why my variable charlie will not appear in the output text box. All the variables are correct in the end ( i checked them with the alert function) but in the end it seems that it just wont show up! any help would be appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<div id="content">

<form name="calc"> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script id="NumberButtons">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#button1').click(function(){
        $('#output').val($(this).val());
    });
   $('#button2').click(function(){
        $('#output').val($(this).val());
    });
   $('#button3').click(function(){
        $('#output').val($(this).val());
    });
   $('#button4').click(function(){
        $('#output').val($(this).val());
    });
   $('#button5').click(function(){
        $('#output').val($(this).val());
    });
   $('#button6').click(function(){
        $('#output').val($(this).val());
    });
   $('#button7').click(function(){
        $('#output').val($(this).val());
    });
   $('#button8').click(function(){
        $('#output').val($(this).val());
    });
   $('#button9').click(function(){
        $('#output').val($(this).val());
    });
   $('#button0').click(function(){
        $('#output').val($(this).val());
    });
   $('#buttonclear').click(function(){
        $('#output').val($(this).val());
    });
  });
</script>
<script id="MathSymbolButtons">
var alpha = 0;
var bravo = 0;
var charlie = 0;

  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#buttonplus').click(function(){
             var alpha = $("#output").val();
             window.alert(alpha)
             });
         $('#buttonequals').click(function(){
              var bravo = $("#output").val();
              window.alert(bravo)
              var charlie = alpha + bravo;
              $('#output').val($(charlie).val());
              });
  });
</script>
 <table>
    <tr>
         <td>
         <input type="text"   id="output">
        <br>
        </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <input type="button" name="one" value = "1" id="button1"> 
        <input type = "button" name = "two" value = "2" id="button2" > 
        <input type = "button" name = "three" value = "3" id="button3"> 
        <input type = "button" name = "four" value = "4"id="button4"> 
        <input type = "button" name = "five" value = "5" id="button5"> 
        <input type = "button" name = "six" value = "6" id="button6"> 
        <input type = "button" name = "seven" value = "7" id="button7"> 
        <input type = "button" name = "eight" value = "8" id="button8"> 
        <input type = "button" name = "nine" value = "9" id="button9"> 
        <input type = "button" name = "zero" value = "0" id="button0"> 
        <input type = "button" name = "add" value = "+" id="buttonplus">
        <input type = "button" name = "evaluate" value = " = "     id="buttonequals"> 
        <br>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove these spaces value = "1"

Comment: [DRY!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: by the way, your code can be optimize, group all the button into one single  line of code `$('#button1, #button2, #button3').click(function(){`

Comment: a single line can do that.  add a same `class` to all of buttons. And `$('class').click(function(){ $('#output').val($(this).val()); })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your current code:

```
var alpha = 0;
var bravo = 0;
var charlie = 0;

$('#buttonplus').click(function(){
  var alpha = $("#output").val();
});

$('#buttonequals').click(function(){
  var bravo = $("#output").val();
  var charlie = alpha + bravo;
  $('#output').val($(charlie).val());
});
```

These are global variables:

```
var alpha = 0;
var bravo = 0;
var charlie = 0;
```

But you're creating new local variables within the `click` handlers:

```
$('#buttonplus').click(function(){
  var alpha = $("#output").val();
});
```

Remove `var` to access the global variables instead:

```
$('#buttonplus').click(function(){
  alpha = $("#output").val();
});
```

---

This code assigns the *string* representation of `#output` to alpha:

```
alpha = $("#output").val();
```

If `alpha` is 2 and `bravo` is 3, then `alpha + bravo` would be `23`.

You can coerce it to a number by prepending a plus sign:

```
alpha = +$("#output").val();
```

---

Finally, instead of this:

```
  $('#output').val($(charlie).val());
```

… do this:

```
  $('#output').val(charlie);
```

---

Corrected code:

```
var alpha = 0;
var bravo = 0;
var charlie = 0;

$('#buttonplus').click(function(){
  alpha = +$("#output").val();
});

$('#buttonequals').click(function(){
  bravo = +$("#output").val();
  charlie = alpha + bravo;
  $('#output').val(charlie);
});
```

Comment: I didn't know that about + sign , I always did *1 to turn into a number

Comment: Yep.  You've got to be somewhat careful, though.  This returns 11:  `alert(+'5'+6)`.  But this returns 56:  `alert(+'5'+'6')`.  Your `*1` trick would work better in the case of the latter.

Comment: (+'5')+(+'6'))  , yea... maybe I'll stick with *1

Answer (score 2):

charlie is not an element, its a variable, so:

```
$('#output').val(charlie);
```

or natively:

```
document.getElementById( 'output' ).value = charlie;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. 'var' in function create new local variables,will not affect to the global one
2. u can't add two string,get number by string * 1
3. $('#output').val(charlie) to set the value

try this:

```
$('#buttonplus').click(function(){
     alpha = $("#output").val();
     //window.alert(alpha)
     });
 $('#buttonequals').click(function(){
      bravo = $("#output").val();
      //window.alert(bravo)
      charlie = alpha * 1 + bravo * 1;
      $('#output').val(charlie);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

There were many problems:

Here's a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/khsm7s0s/

You declared several variables twice. 
You need to force the strings to be numbers so you can add them. 
You treated charlie as a DOM element by putting a jQuery wrapper on  it.

```
var alpha = 0;
var bravo = 0;
var charlie = 0;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#buttonplus').click(function () {
            alpha = $("#output").val();
        });
        $('#buttonequals').click(function () {
            bravo = $("#output").val();
            charlie = Number(alpha) + Number(bravo);
            $('#output').val(charlie);
        });
    });
```

Comment: you left out all the buttons for the numbers which should also all be in one handler

Comment: you're actually probably right , I'm usually careful in questions like this to help out without just typing out a full solution as well - I shouldn't of even said anything

Comment: @ScottSelby - No, you were correct.   I didn't realize he had split the script into two places.    Maybe I'll get half credit!

Answer (score 0):

in first place, `$().val()` is used to extract the value of a document element (such as a textbox), but your variables `charlie` is already a string, so it doesn't make sense to do `$(charlie).val()`

in second place, since they are strings, `alpha + bravo` will concatenate them so in this case, 2 + 3 will be 23 instead of 5, in order to sum them properly you must convert them to ints with `parseInt(alpha)` or `alpha * 1`

in third place, in javascript, your variables are function scoped, that means if you do

```
$('#buttonplus').click(function(){
  var alpha = $("#output").val();
});
```

your variable alpha will only exist inside that function, if you want to access it from the outside you need to do

```
var alpha;
$('#buttonplus').click(function(){
    alpha = $("#output").val();
});
```

otherwise alpha will be undefined

one last note is please don't omit var, the following code will work but is a terrible practice

```
$('#buttonplus').click(function(){
    alpha = $("#output").val();
});
```

in this case, alpha is a global variable and if your page is composed of several files alpha will be defined in the other files too and may even colide with another alpha variable in another file!

so here is a working fiddle of what I just said

http://jsfiddle.net/hxvjhsxd/