# Building a calculator using JQuery, Issues with multiple calculations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been building a calculator with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).  The clear button doesn't work after multiple calculations and further calculations yield incorrect results.

I am looking to improve my solution as well as correct the multiple calculations problem I am running into.

My snippet is below.

```js
var alpha = 0;
var bravo = 0;
var charlie = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#button1').click(function(){
  $('#output').val($(this).val());
 });
 $('#button2').click(function(){
  $('#output').val($(this).val());
 });
 $('#button3').click(function(){
  $('#output').val($(this).val());
 });
 $('#button4').click(function(){
  $('#output').val($(this).val());
 });
 $('#button5').click(function(){
  $('#output').val($(this).val());
 });
 $('#button6').click(function(){
  $('#output').val($(this).val());
 });
 $('#button7').click(function(){
  $('#output').val($(this).val());
 });
 $('#button8').click(function(){
  $('#output').val($(this).val());
 });
 $('#button9').click(function(){
  $('#output').val($(this).val());
 });
 $('#button0').click(function(){
  $('#output').val($(this).val());
 });
 $('#buttonclear').click(function(){
  $('#output').val($(this).val());
 });
});


$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#buttonplus').click(function(){
   alpha = +$("#output").val();
   if (alpha >= 0) {
   $('#buttonequals').click(function(){
   bravo = +$("#output").val();
   charlie = alpha+bravo;
   $('#output').val(charlie);
   return;
    });
   }
 });
 $('#buttonsubtraction').click(function(){
  alpha = +$("#output").val();
  if (alpha >= 0) {
   $('#buttonequals').click(function(){
   bravo = +$("#output").val();
   charlie = alpha-bravo;
   $('#output').val(charlie);
   return;
    });
  }
 });
 $('#buttonmultiply').click(function(){
  alpha = +$("#output").val();
  if (alpha >= 0) {
   $('#buttonequals').click(function(){
   bravo = +$("#output").val();
   charlie = alpha*bravo;
   $('#output').val(charlie);
   return;
    });
  }
 });
 $('#buttondivide').click(function(){
  alpha = +$("#output").val();
  if (alpha >= 0) {
   $('#buttonequals').click(function(){
   bravo = +$("#output").val();
   charlie = alpha/bravo;
   $('#output').val(charlie);
   return;
    });
   }
 });
 $('#buttonclear').click(function(){
  alpha = 0;
  bravo= 0;
  charlie = 0;
 });
});
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="text"   id="output"> <!-- NOTE: The id of the textbox is "output" -->
  <br>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="button" name="one" value = "1" id="button1"> <!-- 1 -->
   <input type = "button" name = "two" value = "2" id="button2" > <!-- 2 -->
   <input type = "button" name = "three" value = "3" id="button3"> <!-- 3 -->
   <input type = "button" name = "add" value = "+" id="buttonplus"> <!-- + -->
   <br />
   <input type = "button" name = "four" value = "4"id="button4"> <!-- 4 -->
   <input type = "button" name = "five" value = "5" id="button5"> <!-- 5 -->
   <input type = "button" name = "six" value = "6" id="button6"> <!-- 6 -->
   <input type = "button" name = "subtract" value = "-" id="buttonsubtraction"> <!-- - -->
   <br />
   <input type = "button" name = "seven" value = "7" id="button7"> <!-- 7 -->
   <input type = "button" name = "eight" value = "8" id="button8"> <!-- 8 -->
   <input type = "button" name = "nine" value = "9" id="button9"> <!-- 9 -->
   <input type = "button" name = "multiply" value = "x" id="buttonmultiply"> <!-- * -->
   <br />
   <input type = "button" name = "clear" value = "ce" id="buttonclear"> <!-- '' -->
   <input type = "button" name = "zero" value = "0" id="button0"> <!-- 0 -->
   <input type = "button" name = "evaluate" value = " = " id="buttonequals"> 
   <input type = "button" name = "divide" value = "&divide;" id="buttondivide"> <!-- / -->
   <br />
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So, you are trying to multiply (output) by (output)?, you just replace the same value here, you need to put it somewhere in a variable !

Comment: I've already answered this in my previous answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30228037/1102585

Comment: Don't setup event handlers inside other event handlers, you will end up getting compounded event firings, unless you remove them at some point

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if you have any questions.  I tried to keep the code fairly self explanatory.

Some helpful links:

[`$("...").data("...")`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)

[`$("...").on("event", function(){ ... })`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Failry overhauled version below.

```js
var currentAction = "";
var memory = 0;

function Update(x)
{
  if(currentAction == ""){
    memory = x;
    return;
  }
  
  switch(currentAction){
    case "ADD":
      memory += x;
      break;
    case "SUB":
      memory = memory - x;
      break;
    case "MUL":
      memory *= x;
      break;
    case "DIV":
      memory = memory / x;
      break;
    default:
      console.warn("Unknown action: " + currentAction);
      break;
  }
}

$(function(){
  var $el = $("#result");
  
  $(".sel-action").on("click", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var input = parseFloat($el.val());
    var action = $this.data("action");
    var clearInput = true;
    switch(action)
    {
      case "CLR":
        memory = 0;
        currentAction = "";
        break;
      case "EQL":
        clearInput = false;
        Update(input);
        $el.val(memory);
        currentAction = "";
        break;
      default:
        Update(input);
        currentAction = action;
    }
    
    if(clearInput)
      $el.val("");
  });
  
  $(".sel-input").on("click", function(){
     $el.val($el.val() + $(this).data("value"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4"><input id="result" value="" style="width: 110px" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button class="sel-input" data-value="1">1</button></td>
      <td><button class="sel-input" data-value="2">2</button></td>
      <td><button class="sel-input" data-value="3">3</button></td>
      <td><button class="sel-action" data-action="ADD">+</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button class="sel-input" data-value="4">4</button></td>
      <td><button class="sel-input" data-value="5">5</button></td>
      <td><button class="sel-input" data-value="6">6</button></td>
      <td><button class="sel-action" data-action="SUB">-</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button class="sel-input" data-value="7">7</button></td>
      <td><button class="sel-input" data-value="8">8</button></td>
      <td><button class="sel-input" data-value="9">9</button></td>
      <td><button class="sel-action" data-action="MUL">x</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button class="sel-action" data-action="CLR">C</button></td>
      <td><button class="sel-input" data-value="0">0</button></td>
      <td><button class="sel-action" data-action="EQL">=</button></td>
      <td><button class="sel-action" data-action="DIV">&divide;</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Just a friendly warning, if this is by chance for homework Professors frequently check stackoverflow for solutions to their problems.  Buyer beware!

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#buttonclear').click(function(){
    $('#output').val('');
});
```